# view areas with canvas and createjs/easeljs

Tags: javascript, canvas, easeljs, createjs

I am working with CreateJs and the whole program I am working on is within a canvas element. Within that element I have a few (5-6 areas) where all the elements within it, should now go outside and should be cut.
I have made an image for you that explains the situation. The yellow part is the program. The red border is an area, where all elements within it should not go outside (I put an image in it, which is cut)

[image]

Do you have any idea how I can do that?

Comment: put them all in a container, and mask the container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as mentioned by Marton I just masked the container. Here the code:

```
var container = new createjs.Container();
var maskShape = new craetejs.Shape();

maskShape.graphics.drawRect(50, 50, 200, 200); // x, y, width, height

container.mask = maskShape;
```